# play video from particular time stamp in h264 frames in swift

Tags: ios, swift, h.264, uislider, cmtime

I’m playing h.264 frames from file, now I want add custom controls to it, added the slider and slider moving as per video but when I seek (backward/forward) the slider position I want to play from updated timestamp

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Could you please provide the code you are using to display your video?

Comment: Find out how to detect the event for seek ending (is when you stop the seek at your required position), then use the slider position to set a play time just like how you _"added the slider and slider moving as per video"_.